# How to manually edit STATE tracking in Meltano?

Tags: meltano

There are several scenarios where we it would be useful to manually edit job state in Meltano. For example, if a table is accidentally deleted in the target SQL warehouse, the user may want to remove the incremental bookmark for just that table while not fully deleting the state entry for the entire job ID.

What's the best way to alter that STATE record?

Answer (score 1):

There are two options as of now:

1. Dump and re-import state. Export the state with the `--dump` option in [meltano elt](https://docs.meltano.com/reference/command-line-interface#elt), manually edit the STATE json, and then reimport using `--state`.
2. Update the corresponding row within the Meltano system DB. Looking up the job's row in the Meltano system DB, manually edit the row within the database.

Comment: Related: new feature proposal which would enable a third option of altering state via CLI: https://gitlab.com/meltano/meltano/-/issues/2754